# How to match text in a cell to regex and keep only the text which matches regex?

Tags: python, regex, openpyxl

What I am trying to do: There is a large excel sheet with a lot haphazard customer information. I want to sort the email address and other data in a set format in a new excel file.

I can't quite figure out how to match the cell text(which will have some format like Address Email squished togethe and similar) with the regex and to keep only the regex data in a list.

Would really appreciate some help. Thanks

```
import sys, os, openpyxl
def sort_email_from_xl():
    sheet = sheet_select()   #Opens the worksheet
    emailRegex = re.compile(r'''([a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@+[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+(\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}))''',re.VERBOSE)
    customeremails = []
    for row in range(0, max_row):
        if cell.text == emailRegex:
            mail = cell.text
            customeremails.append(mail)
            return customeremails
    print(customeremails)
```

Answer (score 3):

This code should work (I could only test the regex part though):

```
import sys, os, openpyxl
def sort_email_from_xl():
    sheet = sheet_select()   #Opens the worksheet
    emailRegex = re.compile(".*?([a-zA-Z0-9\._%+\-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.\-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}).*?")
    customeremails = []
    for row in range(0, max_row):
        if emailRegex.match(cell.text):
            mail = emailRegex.match(cell.text).groups()[0]
            cell.text = mail
            customeremails.append(mail)
    print(customeremails)
```

There were many problems with your code. First about the regex:

- the regex was not allowing text around your email address, added that with `.*?` at start and end
- you don't need the `re.VERBOSE` part as you'd only need it if you want to add inline comments to your regex, [see doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.VERBOSE)
- you allowed email addresses with many `@` in between
- you matched the TLD separately, that's unneeded

Now, the email regex works for basic usage, but I'd definitively recommend to take a proven email regex from other answers on Stackoverflow.

Then: with `emailRegex.match(cell.text)` you can check if the `cell.text` matches your regex and with `emailRegex.match(cell.text).groups()[0]` you extract only the matching part. You had one `return` statement too much as well.

> For some reason the above code is giving me a NameError: name 'max_row' is not defined

You need to correct the looping through the rows e.g. like [documented here](https://gist.github.com/yosemitebandit/2869767)

Comment: thanks I am looking into all the errors I made. For some reason the above code is giving me a `NameError: name 'max_row' is not defined`. I assumed this is becasue I should have used `sheet.max_row` instead. Tried it and now I am getting `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'max_row'`. I just went through the docs and I think it might be because I am calling the sheet with the name I assigned, rather than a Sheet2. Is there a way around it? I would rather call the sheet with the name I assign.

Comment: @sid yes, the code around the for loop also needs corrections, I added a link to a basic python script within the answer

Comment: No, the Sheet2 doesn't seem to be a problem. Tested and now it says: Sheet2 doesn't exist.

Comment: Hmmm..I changed the code a bit: `for row in sheet.iter_rows():`
        `if emailRegex.match(cell.text):`
            `mail = emailRegex.match(cell.text).group[0]`
            `cell.text = mail`
            `customeremails.append(mail)` but _AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'iter_rows'_

Comment: can you paste your full code (or at least the relevant part) to gist.github.com and send the link? `sheet = sheet_select()` calls a function which is not visible in the code above

Comment: Here it is: [Link](https://gist.github.com/SidGoy/9a84153fd007083f9647c011d4cea4d7) Thanks for all the help. I am very new to coding but learning everyday by making mistakes. :)

Comment: there's a missing `return` in this line: `wb.get_sheet_by_name('Maharashtra')`, maybe there are some more errors

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133717/discussion-between-hansaplast-and-sid).