# Match `cell.value` to regex using python?

Tags: python, regex, openpyxl

For some reason the text in excel cells is only readable as `cell.value`.

`emailRegex = re.compile(".*?([a-zA-Z0-9\._%+\-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.\-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}).*?")`

When I try:

```
for row in ws.iter_rows():
       for cell in row:
            if emailRegex.match(cell.text):
                    mail = emailRegex.match(cell.text).group[0]
                    cell.text = mail
                    customeremails.append(mail)

print(customeremails)
```

> AttributeError: Object has no str

```
for row in ws.iter_rows():
        for cell in row:
            if emailRegex.match(str(cell.value)):
                  mail = emailRegex.match(str(cell.value)).group[0]
                  cell.text = mail
                  customeremails.append(mail)

print(customeremails)
```

> SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Been trying to find a solution for 8 hours now.

Edited:

Updated errors and emailRegex.

Also:

```
for row in ws.iter_rows():
            for cell in row:
                 content = cell.text
                 print(content)
```

Gives an error that cell contains no string

```
for row in ws.iter_rows():
            for cell in row:
                 content = cell.value
                 print(content)
```

Gives the following: (snip)

> None
>
> None
>
> 4020110
>
> None
>
> Nagdevi
>
> None
>
> Mumbai
>
> store@xxx.com

Comment: Please show the complete error message.

Comment: What is `emailRegex`?

Comment: `group` is a function on the match result.

Comment: Updated with errors and emailRegex and other details.

Comment: How many questions about this problem are you going to post?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to match text in a cell to regex and keep only the text which matches regex?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41779655/how-to-match-text-in-a-cell-to-regex-and-keep-only-the-text-which-matches-regex)

Answer (score 0):

You called `group` incorrectly.  You should call it as a function and not an array.

```
# for python 3
emailRegex = re.compile(r".*?([a-zA-Z0-9\._%+\-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.\-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}).*?")
for row in ws.iter_rows():
    for cell in row:
        if cell.value and isinstance(cell.value, str) and emailRegex.match(cell.value):
            mail = emailRegex.match(cell.value)
            if mail:
                mail = mail.group(0) # use parentheses to call the function!!!! 
                cell.text = mail
                customeremails.append(mail)

print(customeremails)
```

Comment: Hi, I updated the info in the OP. Thanks for all the help. I just tried the code above and getting a _SyntaxError: invalid syntax_ in `if cell.value and isinstance(cell.value, str) emailRegex.match(cell.value):`

Comment: Typo:  forgot the word and.