# Invalid syntax error in an `if` statement which I am unable to understand?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, if-statement, openpyxl

I went line by line and came up to this error.

> SyntaxError: invalid syntax

In, the `emailRegex` gets highlighted

`if cell.value and isinstance(cell.value, str) emailRegex.match(cell.value):`

The complete code(python3.x)

```
import re, openpyxl, os, sys
def sort_email_from_xl():
    loc = input("Please enter path of the file:")
    os.chdir(loc)
    file = input("Filename:")
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(file, use_iterators=True)
    sheet = input("Which Sheet do you want to email?\n")
    return sheet
    wb.get_sheet_by_name(sheet)
    ws = wb.get_sheet_by_name(sheet)
    emailRegex = re.compile(r".*?([a-zA-Z0-9\._%+\-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.\-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}).*?")
    customeremails = []        #works fine till here in idle
for row in ws.iter_rows():
    for cell in row:
        if cell.value and isinstance(cell.value, str) emailRegex.match(cell.value):
            mail = emailRegex.match(cell.value)
            if mail:
                mail = mail.group(0) # use parentheses to call the function 
                cell.text = mail
                customeremails.append(mail)

print(customeremails)
```

Can someone point to a resource where I can read what exactly is going wrong? I have been trying to sort this function out for almost 12 hours now, with help from SO and reading through docs.

Is the code fine after current error?

Thanks

Comment: Please proofread your code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to match text in a cell to regex and keep only the text which matches regex?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41779655/how-to-match-text-in-a-cell-to-regex-and-keep-only-the-text-which-matches-regex)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed `and` between predicates:

```
if cell.value and isinstance(cell.value, str) and emailRegex.match(cell.value):
                                              ^^^
```

Comment: Tried to change it:     `for row in ws.iter_rows():`
     `for cell in row:`
`if cell.value and isinstance(cell.value, str) and emailRegex.match(cell.value):`
`   mail = emailRegex.match(cell.value)`
`   if mail:`
`    mail = mail.group(0)`
`    cell.text = mail`
`    customeremails.append(mail)
`print(customeremails)`
 still getting `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` no highlight now though.

Comment: @Sid, Except the part that I pointed in the answer, there's no syntax error. I tried in my machine. Is there another code that is not listed in the question?

Comment: No, I made sure to include all the code. I will give it another try using the script to call it.

Comment: Ok. when calling the function from another script. The new error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\Functionsexce Test.py", line 4, in <module>
    sort_email_from_xl()_
  File "C:\Python34\Functionsexce.py", line 60, in sort_email_from_xl
    cell.text = mail
AttributeError: 'ReadOnlyCell' object has no attribute 'text'

Comment: Managed to fix it. Removed the `cell.text = mail`. Now I have a list with all emails. Thanks to a lot for all the help.

Comment: @Sid, Nice to see that you solved the problem yourself. Happy programming!

Comment: Wouldn't have been able to without all the help from SO. But learning more with every mistake.

Comment: A bit confused again, its a very small thing and I didn't want to post up a question. The list isn't getting saved at the end of the above function in to `customeremails`. Should I add a return statement?

Comment: @Sid, What do you mean saved? ... If you meant `print(customeremails)` print `[]`, you need to check if the regular expression is correct. It deserve separated question.