# Take a list and write the data to a new xlsx file using python and openpyxl

Tags: python, openpyxl

So a lot of help and head scratching over docs later:

```
for row in ws.iter_rows():
        for cell in row:
            if cell.value and isinstance(cell.value, str) and emailRegex.match(cell.value):
                mail = emailRegex.match(cell.value)
                if mail:
                    mail = mail.group(0)
                    customeremails.append(mail)
print(customeremails)
```

The print command gets me:

> ['store@xxxx.com', 'xxxx@yahoo.co.in', 'xxxx@gmail.com']

Now I wanted to add the following, tryint to get this list into a new excel file starting from cell B2:

```
                #Adding the below before print(customeremails)
                os.chdir("C:\Python34")  
                wb = Workbook()
                dest_filename = 'trial.xlsx'
                ws1 = wb.active
                ws1.title = sheet
                i = 2
                for i,mail in enumerate(customeremails):
                    ws1.cell(row = i, column = 2).value = mail
                    i = i+1
                    return i
                wb.save(filename = dest_filename)
```

The file gets created the worksheet gets renamed. But I only get one of the email addresses in the list.

Comment: I don't understand: you `return` from within your loop. It can't work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to match text in a cell to regex and keep only the text which matches regex?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41779655/how-to-match-text-in-a-cell-to-regex-and-keep-only-the-text-which-matches-regex)

Comment: This is about the sixth version of this question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 problems here:

- you're returning `i` from within the loop: useless, and prevents the file from being created properly
- you're using `enumerate` and change/initialize `i`: choose. I'd let `enumerate` do the job.

My proposal (added optional param to `enumerate` so `i` starts at `2`, row cannot be `0`):

```
for i,mail in enumerate(customeremails,2):
    ws1.cell(row = i, column = 2).value = mail
wb.save(filename = dest_filename)
```

Comment: Thanks. The `return` statement. I was trying everything I could come up with. :) Reading up on `enumerate` and what I did with `i` now.